# Simulate Up Arrow Press in Linux

Tags: php, linux, echo, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to simulate the up-arrow being pressed over echo?

To, hopefully, make this clearer, allow me to explain the premise.  I'm controlling omxplayer on my Raspberry Pi using a PHP server on the Pi.  In order to input commands into the player, I have a FIFO input to it, which I can send commands to from a PHP web page.

To stop the video, the player requires the 'q' key to be pressed, which I implemented on my PHP page as follows: shell_exec("echo -n q > $pipe");.

However, to skip forward 10 minutes it requires the up arrow to be pressed.  So, does anyone know how I can echo the up-arrow (into the pipe)?

I hope that's clear.  I've tried sending the escape sequence "echo -n \c[[A > $pipe", but that didn't work :(

Thank you very much in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [a thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-echo-the-arrow-keys-825773/) regarding this. The following code should work:

```
shell_exec("echo -n $'\e'[A > $pipe");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - not sure how I missed that on my google search, but thanks!

Comment: don't worry. the question was interesting anyway

Comment: Thanks!  Just in case you are interested, I've uploaded the PHP pages to github: "https://github.com/waggy55/RPi_PHP_VIDEO".  But be warned: it's quite "hacky" as I'm trying to learn PHP in the process.